# When running powershell as admin from mapped drive, no output from submodules?

Tags: powershell

I have a ps1 script with the following import (Most of this was debugging for this issue):

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent;
Write-Host "Importing Modules:";
try {
    Write-Host "  $($scriptPath)\modules\functions-logging.psm1... " -NoNewline
    Import-Module "$($scriptPath)\modules\functions-logging.psm1";
    Write-Host "Done";
} catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

The  `functions-logging.psm1` submodule does very little other than a few `Write-Host` lines.

If I open Powershell normally and run the command, it functions as expected and I see all the output.  However, if I run powershell as an admin, the script seems to run properly but I see no output from the submodule at all.

Regular output:

> ```
> PS P:\!Scripts\Dev> .\ops-healthcheck.ps1
> Importing Modules:
>   P:\!Scripts\Dev\modules\functions-logging.psm1... Done
> Getting checkin URL... Found URL
> Task not installed.
> PS P:\!Scripts\Dev>
> ```

Administrator Output:

> ```
> PS P:\!Scripts\DEV> .\ops-healthcheck.ps1
> Importing Modules:
>   P:\!Scripts\DEV\modules\functions-logging.psm1... Done
> PS P:\!Scripts\DEV>
> ```

What is causing this?

---

Update: It looks like this is related to running the script from a mapped network drive.

Here is some output of running the exact same scripts copied to the C: drive vs the mapped drive (both as administrator):

> ```
> PS C:\!Scripts\DEV> .\ops-healthcheck.ps1
> Importing Modules:
>   C:\!Scripts\DEV\modules\functions-logging.psm1... Done
> Getting checkin URL... Found URL
> Checking in... Success
> PS C:\!Scripts\DEV> p:
> PS P:\!Scripts\DEV> .\ops-healthcheck.ps1
> Importing Modules:
>   P:\!Scripts\DEV\modules\functions-logging.psm1... Done
> PS P:\!Scripts\DEV>
> ```

The drive was mapped under the Administrator context, so I'm not sure why this would cause an issue.

Comment: If the rest of the code runs as expected, `Write-Host` may be the problem. You should try using something like `Write-Verbose` / `Write-Output` / `Write-Error` / `Write-Warning` / etc. instead and perhaps enable `[CmdletBinding()]` with your `.ps1` script for common params like `-Verbose`. The way that `Write-Host` is outputting data has historically been hard to work with until PowerShell 5. Checkout https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6

Comment: Updated question with new information that may be useful.